# How to properly nmap websocket port?

Tags: sockets, websocket, nmap

JavaScript based HTML5 application is using web-socket port 10060 for communication with development server (server url is: ws://mydomain.tld:10060).

However I have problem: it seems that development server is only accessible from one local network, but not from another through websockets. I can access from that network: ping, ssh, even html: except make websocket connection to server.

How to properly use nmap and other utilities to see if ports are open and accessible. I know how to check tcp ports, but what about websocket, how to properly check them? Are they any different?

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket is implemented on top of TCP so a regular TCP port scan would work.

Actually WebSocket begin as a single HTTP request and response before upgrading the protocol to WebSocket.